# Convert list (array) to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to convert PHP list (array), i.e.

```
array("start", "end", "coords")
```

into associative array with truthy values (just to be able to test the presence/absence of key quickly), i.e. to something like this:

```
array(
    "start" => 1,
    "end" => 1,
    "coords" => 1
)
```

Is there any more elegant way to do it than this?

```
array_fill_keys($ar, 1)
```

Comment: What can possibly be more elegant than one call to a built-in function?

Comment: @Felix I know it sounds weird, but I find this way of doing it rather clumsy...

Comment: You can iterate over the array if it makes you feel better ;) PHP does not have sets so this is really the best you can do. You can create your own function of course: `function setify($array) { return array_fill_keys($ar, true);}` or something like that. Or what would you expect?

Comment: is there any function like array_fill_keys?

Comment: @sandeep: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php

Comment: If the number of elements is relatively small, a linear search is roughly equivalent to allocating a hash and looking it up, so if that's the case you don't need to add the extra complexity.

Comment: @cgwyllie, yes, but with "quickly" I also mean the elegancy of code - so instead of writing `array_search("coords", $ar) !== false` I just write `$ar["coords"]` and that's it.

Comment: Evaluating truthiness in short-hand is 'elegant' only for as long as the assumption the key actually exists holds true. As soon as it doesn't, you'll get undefined key/index notices.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop, that's why I switched `E_NOTICE` off. There's no reason to spoil your code with bullshit just because PHP is so rigid. There's absolutely no benefit of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably no more elegant solution than `array_fill_keys($ar, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `array_flip` that does this.

http://php.net/array_flip

Doing `array_flip` on an array and then using `isset` turned out to be much faster than doing `in_array` for me.

But note that this is only useful when you're going to be searching the array multiple times.

Comment: `in_array` is slow anyways (compared to `isset`), as it has to do a linear search. `array_flip` is a possibility but note that the first entry will have a value of `0` and therefore does not evaluate to `true` (e.g. `if($arr[firstEntry])`). Of course one should use `isset` anyways, so the actual values don't really matter (as long as they are not `null`).

Comment: @Tomas: How else are you testing the presence of an element? Just doing `if($arr[value])` will give you a `Notice:` if the key is not in the array.

Comment: yes, `in_array` is slow. But if I am using this method to check if a value exists in an array, it has to process each item in the array anyways. And I'm sure the time to hash a string and make it an array key is longer than the time taken whether it's equal to the `$needle`. Also, this method takes up more memory - but it's great if you are checking if lots of strings.

Comment: @Thomas, then just say `$result[$originalArray[0]] = 1` and now you can be assured that every key points to a value that evaluates to `true`.